# Log inside Sidekiq worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I'm trying to log the progress of my sideqik worker using `tail -f log/development.log` in development and `heroku logs` in production.

However, everything inside the worker and everything called by the worker does not get logged. In the code below, only TEST 1 gets logged.

How can I log everything inside the worker and the classes the worker calls?

```
# app/controllers/TasksController.rb
def import_data
  Rails.logger.info "TEST 1" # shows up in development.log
  DataImportWorker.perform_async
  render "done"           
end

# app/workers/DataImportWorker.rb
class DataImportWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform    
    Rails.logger.info "TEST 2" # does not show up in development.log

    importer = Importer.new
    importer.import_data
  end
end


# app/controllers/services/Importer.rb    
class Importer  
  def import_data
    Rails.logger.info "TEST 3" # does not show up in development.log
  end
end
```

**Update**

I still don't understand why `Rails.logger.info` or `Sidekiq.logger.info` don't log into the log stream. Got it working by replacing `Rails.logger.info` with `puts`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a `Sidekiq.logger` and simply `logger` reference that you can use within your workers.  The default should be to STDOUT and you should just direct your output in production to the log file path of your choice.

Comment: Thanks. `logger.info "Some log"` logs into the terminal window where I launched `bundle exec sidekiq` but not in development.log. I tried `bundle exec sidekiq 2>&1 | logger -t sidekiq` but then the logs appear nowhere.

Comment: Same issue. This should not be marked as a solution.

Answer (score 3):

It works in rails 6:

```
# config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

Rails.logger = Sidekiq.logger
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Sidekiq.logger
```

Answer (score 2):

@migu, have you tried the below command in the `config/initializer.rb` ?

```
Rails.logger = Sidekiq::Logging.logger
```

Answer (score 1):

I found [this solution](https://dev.to/snaka/set-the-sidekiq-log-level-to-the-rails-log-level-3e74), it seems to work well.

Sidekiq uses the Ruby Logger class with default Log Level as `INFO`, and its settings are independent from Rails.

You may  set the Sidekiq Log Level for the `Logger` used by Sidekiq in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`:

```rb
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.logger.level = Rails.logger.level
end
```